# Attachments don't show up in Junit report

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I am running automation test with Cucumber, Capybara, and Selenium on Jenkins server. I have installed Junit Reporter, Junit Attachment plugins for Jenkins and I can have Junit reports worked. However, in Junit Reports, I don't see attachments for failed scenarios. 
This is the way I am using: 
In support/hooks.rb:

```
After do |scenario|
  #DeferredGarbageCollection.reconsider
  if scenario.failed?
    page.driver.browser.save_screenshot("#{scenario.__id__}.png")
    embed("#{scenario.__id__}.png", "image/png", "SCREENSHOT")
    # For Junit Reports
    $stdout.write "[[ATTACHMENT | File.absolute_path(#{scenario.__id__}.png)]]"
  end

  Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
end
```

I have checked on "Publish test attachments" in Configure in Jenkins test. 
I also saw that attachment has been written to XML report file.

```
<system-out>
    <![CDATA[[[ATTACHMENT|/var/jenkins_home/jobs/core_huy-test-2784263---Core_Huy__ticket-1317--Core__master/workspace/cucumber_selenium/69948866284720.png]]]]>
</system-out>
```

But I don't see the attachment displayed in Test Result page or any other pages. 
Have anyone experienced this issue? Please help me to solve this. Thanks.